# Xamarin Failed chmod

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I try to run ios app in Xamarin I got below error,I try to run emulator on Mac ,simulator running but suddenly gives bellow error,How can I solve this?

```
Failed to chmod /Users/rota/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/158B85A8-33B8-47E8-8C29-D76673199594/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Bundle/Application/FEFBB055-A70C-4D31-BBC8-0A2A0873B5D4/RotaMobilNew2017.app/RotaMobilNew2017 : No such file or directory. Please check the logs for more details.
The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: Either you have not selected the right provisioning profile or your info plist could be on production setting take a look

Comment: I selected provisining at Visual studio side in Windows but I got same error

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting the right one and you have all the required keychains?